# Submit and download data to a website from iOS

Tags: iphone, file-upload, upload, download, nsurl

So in my app, I want my users to be able to fill out some information and have it uploaded to me website/server.  The user can upload their info and look at other peoples info.  I would like to keep the list of people in an array so I can fill a UITableView with the list of people's names.  The basic information is just text and I can put that into an array or dictionary or something.  But then how should I get it on my website.

Then, how do I download that data and more from the website.

my website is through Yahoo small business and I have written plists and uploaded them in the file manager and then read the arrays from there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a basic http form which can returns data as **JSON** or everything else.

And to interact with it, use the [ASI-HTTP-Request library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), you'll be able to submit a form with POST data (for example) and to get returned data like a JSON array.

Comment: That sounds great but I would have no Idea where to start with this whole JSON thing and even ASI-HTTP-Request Library

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can approach this.  The simplest might be just creating a server side service where you POST some [JSON](http://www.json.org/) with the data you wish to store on the server.  You could implement a similar service for downloading the same data from your site.